# Modelling the Cost of Risk

Tags: risk-management, credit-risk, self-study

I would like to read something about the cost of risk. Could anyone recommend some reference about how it is calculated or modelled?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Cost of credit risk in what capacity?

Comment: It is mentioned in this report: https://www.unicreditgroup.eu/content/dam/unicreditgroup/documents/en/investors/third-pillar-basel/2013/BASEL-2-PILLAR-III-DISCLOSURE-AS-AT-DECEMBER-31_2013.pdf There is also a presentation here: http://www2.humusoft.cz/www/papers/finsem13/finsem13-neckar.pdf

Comment: It is defined on Page 280 (took me a while to get there) as: *Cost of risk* The ratio between loan loss provisions and loans and receivables with customers. It is one of the indicators of the bank assets’ level of risk: the lower the ratio, the less risky the bank assets.

Comment: And what about the presentation? It talks about "cost of credit risk", and consider the cost of risk as a method to calculate it (slide 18). I guess the interesting case is when $Cost Of  Risk = provisions/reserves$. How can I model this quantity?